# Detach a linux process from pseudo-tty, but keep the tty running?

Tags: linux, debugging, terminal, gdb

I want to debug a console linux application with 2 xterm windows: one window used for gdb and another used for the application (e.g. mc).

What I do now is run 'tty && sleep 1024d' in the second xterm window (this gives me its pseudo-tty name) and then run 'tty ' in gdb to redirect the program to that other xterm window. However, GDB warns that it cannot set a controlling terminal and certain minor functions don't work (e.g. handling window resizing), as 'sleep 1024d' is still running on that xterm window.

Any better way to do it (rather than launching the process from the shell and attaching to it from gdb)?

Answer (score 2):

I have somewhat modified the program given in a related bug to store the filename somewhere
http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11403

here is an example using it:

$ xterm -e './disowntty ~/tty.tmp' & sleep 1 && gdb --tty $(cat ~/tty.tmp) /usr/bin/links

```
/* tty;exec disowntty  */
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
static void
end (const char *msg)
{
  perror (msg);
  for (;;)
    pause ();
}
int
main (int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  FILE *tty_name_file;
  const char *tty_filename;

  if (argc <= 1)
    return 1;
  else
    tty_filename = argv[1];

  void (*orig) (int signo);
  setbuf (stdout, NULL);
  orig = signal (SIGHUP, SIG_IGN);
  if (orig != SIG_DFL)
    end ("signal (SIGHUP)");
  /* Verify we are the sole owner of the tty.  */
  if (ioctl (STDIN_FILENO, TIOCSCTTY, 0) != 0)
    end ("TIOCSCTTY");
  printf("%s %s\n", tty_filename, ttyname(STDIN_FILENO));
  tty_name_file = fopen(tty_filename, "w");
  fprintf(tty_name_file, "%s\n", ttyname(STDIN_FILENO));
  fclose(tty_name_file);

  /* Disown the tty.  */
  if (ioctl (STDIN_FILENO, TIOCNOTTY) != 0)
    end ("TIOCNOTTY");
  end ("OK, disowned");

  return 1;
}
```

Comment: fwiw the reason for reimplementing the tty name writing inside the program is that, xterm -e 'tty | cat >tmp.tty && disowntty' ends up calling bash, which then keeps us from disowning the tty.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. Any chance to do it via command-line stty without making a separate program?